# Sharing Wireless Connection with Mac

Tags: windows, mac, wireless-networking

There is a wireless network secured with WPA 2.We have a mac and a old XP.

Unfortunately, the XP is not updated to connect to WPA 2 networks, but we cannot change the security settings on the router. 
But the mac can connect to the network.

Is there a way to get the PC to connect to the Mac which connects to the internet and therefore get them all on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an Ethernet cable. Then, connect your Mac to the Wi-Fi access point, and open up *System Preferences » Sharing*. Here, select *Internet Sharing* and choose the following settings:

- Share your connection from Wi-Fi
- To Computers using Ethernet

Then, enable Internet Sharing.

[image]

---

Now, connect the Ethernet cable from your Mac's Ethernet port to the PC's. On the PC, make sure you've enabled automatic IP configuration by going to *Control Panel* and *Network Connections*.  On the *Local Area Connection*, right-click and select *Properties*.

Under the *General* tab, under *TCP/IP*, select *Properties* again. Here, select *Obtain an IP address automatically* and *Obtain DNS server address automatically*.